# Установленный GTK+ имеет слишком низкую версию, чтобы работать с Glade?

Tags: c, windows, gtk, glade

Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Скачал **MSYS2**, из него поставил **Glade** и **GTK+**. Сами **GTK+** и **Glade** по отдельности работают, но при попытке загрузить в программу форму из 
*.glade* файла возникает ошибка, в описании которой написано:

```
form.glade: required gtk+ version 3.20, current version is 2.24
```

На сайте **GTK+** написано, что сделать, чтобы использовать **GTK+** и **Glade** из-под **Windows**:

```
https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
```

Я делаю все в точности, как там написано, но... Установленный таким образом **GTK+** имеет слишком низкую версию, чтобы работать с установленным таким способом **Glade**?

Хотя, если посмотреть через **MSYS2**, то становится ясно, что установленный **GTK+** имеет версию 3.22...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если посмотреть настройки проекта в **Glade**, то окажется, что проект требует **GTK+** версии 3.20...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Безумие...

Comment: *"при попытке загрузить в программу"* - а программа использует GTK 3.20?

Comment: Не знаю, пытался разобраться с шаблоном-скриптом создания проекта GTK в Code::Blocks, но побороть его так и не удалось. Никаких параметров, задающих используемую версию в настройках проекта найти не удалось. Так же пытался сменить в путях все gtk 2.0 на gtk 3.0. Такой вариант тоже не прошел. Не знаю, как это настраивать, потому что не смог найти туториал по зависимостям путей/библиотек друг от друга.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, мне удалось побороть эту ситуацию эвристическим методом *научного тыка*.

Каюсь, мои претензии к официальному туториалу **GTK+** и **MSYS2** оказались ничем не обоснованы.

**MSYS2** ставит абсолютно корректные и согласованные пакеты вместе со всеми зависимостями. Проблема заключалась в том, что шаблон проекта в **Code::Blocks** для **GTK+** устарел и создает проект **GTK+ 2.0**

Для того, чтобы создать проект **GTK+ 3.0** можно обойтись и стандартным шаблоном **Консольное приложение C/C++**. Далее, для того, чтобы проект понял, что значит:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

В **Build options** проекта нужно задать пару флагов.

**Compiler settings->Other compiler options:**

```
`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags`
```

**Linker settings->Other linker options:**

```
`pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --libs`
```

Если честно, я имею только общие представления, что делают эти флаги. Поделитесь, кто на опыте.

Самое приятное, что для компиляции проекта используется **MinGW-64**, устанавливающийся вместе с **GTK+**, **Glade** и всем остальным. Поэтому, достаточно указать только пути к компилятору, настроить **toolchain** и все. Никаких плясок с десятками путей к **GTK+** и переменными окружения не нужно.

Comment: Мораль - не пользоваться шаблонами проектов в CodeBlocks и всегда выбирать пустой проект. У меня с libSDL похожие проблемы были.